# transposing multiple values in a single row in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like

```
id  var1 var2
1   A1   B1
1   A2   B2
1   A3   B3
```

How can I get the data like

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1 A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for pivot

Comment: I would rather do it from application side like php, java

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you may potentially need more columns depending on how many records occur for each `id` group, I would suggest an alternative approach using group concatenation:

```
SELECT
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', var1, var2)) AS output
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you have more columns to add, you only would need to add additional columns to `CONCAT_WS`.

Comment: OP want's it in seperate column like v1, v2 .. not in one column

Comment: @fa06 It would be a lot of work to write an exact query for that, because we either need to use `ROW_NUMBER`, or, more likely, dynamic SQL.  Especially if the number of rows per group is variable.  Using `GROUP_CONCAT` is an alternative which is much easier IMHO.

Comment: yes you are right it is a pivot problem and in mysql pivoting is a tough one to write, however I didn't give you downvote

Comment: i don't know why this answer get downvoted..

Comment: @dwir182  may b op given him down vote cause this answer is not covered his problem solution